# Spring MVC Controller is not called -but compiling process seems fine

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, ant

I tried to create a little Java-web-project, while using Spring MVC Framework.
To build my project, I use ant.
The compiling process seems to work, but unfortunately my controller class( and method)  is never been called.

Here are my solution files.

*web.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>HelpMe</display-name>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/test/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

*mvc-servlet.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.please.help.me" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

*Controller-class:*

```
package com.please.help.me;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/page1")
    public String showWelcomePage1() {
        System.out.println("show page 1...");
        return "page1";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/page2")
    public String showWelcomePage2() {
        System.out.println("show page 2...");
        return "page2";
    }

}
```

*ant-build-file: (build.xml)*

```
<project name="HelpMeProject" default="compile" basedir="." xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
    <description>
  Build file for not working project
  </description>

    <!-- set global properties for this build -->
    <property name="src" location="src" />
    <property name="build" location="build" />
    <property name="lib" location="lib" />

    <property name="classes" location="${build}\WEB-INF\classes" />

    <path id="project-classpath">
        <fileset dir="${build}\WEB-INF\lib" includes="*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${src}" />
    </path>

    <target name="compile" description="compile the source" >

        <delete dir="${lib}" />
        <delete dir="${build}" />

        <mkdir dir="${lib}" />

        <!-- Do ivy retrieve -->
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib}/[type]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />

        <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
        <mkdir dir="${build}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build}\WEB-INF\lib" />
        <mkdir dir="${classes}" />

        <copy todir="${build}\WEB-INF\lib">
            <fileset dir="${lib}\jar" />
            <fileset dir="${lib}\bundle" />
        </copy>

        <copy todir="${build}">
            <fileset dir="web" />
        </copy>

        <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}" classpathref="project-classpath" debug="true" />

    </target>

</project>
```

*and finally my tomcat deployment descriptor: (helpme.xml)*

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context crossContext="true" docBase="c:\..myPath..\HelpMe\build\"  path="/helpme">

</Context>
```

After running the compile-ant-script, everything seems fine. Tomcat starts as it should do, but it doesn't matter which URL I call -the controller won't be touched.
This is what I tried:

- localhost:8080/
- localhost:8080/test
- localhost:8080/test/page1
- localhost:8080/page1

I looked for similiar topics, but did not find an solution for that problem. Maybe you can help me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't use Ant and Ya Wangs answer should help.

Comment: you are deploying the web application inside Tomcat `webapps` folder. Then can you provide the folder structure of deployed app.I suspect the deployment is not correct or Tomcat didn't load the app

Comment: have you tried with  /test/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case if you have any request mapping as `/test/` in controller then

```
localhost:8080/test/
```

it will will work.

If you want any url after /test/ needs to be work like :

```
localhost:8080/test/page1
```

you need to map it in web.xml as :

```
/test/*
```

as I commented.

in url /test/*, the `*` means any thing after /test/

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<url-pattern>/test/</url-pattern>
```

to

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

then localhost:8080/page1 at least should work fine

is this a maven project? If so you can you show us the pom.xml ?

> Most people start their webapp with Requestmapping "/"

If you want a quick start to Spring MVC Programming no junk or setup use STS (spring tools suite) although someone gave me a hard time because I like the tool saying it came with a pre-setup tomcat therefore lessening the experience while that is true but eventually you will need to near how to deploy manually to tomcat anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Changing the url-pattern works  - but I really want it to run in case of calling ".../test/". I don't understand why this is not working ?! Any idea?

Comment: Solved! I don't know why - but changing the pattern to "/test/*" works. ?!

Comment: @CodeCannibal Yeah that is what you would do if you wanted it to do test/ something something. The thing is / means all urls and if you want test/ you need to do test/* which is all urls that follows test. Now you know.